# Listener.ora Location

Tags: oracle

What is the location of the **Listener.Ora** file in Windows OS?
I need to edit  that file and I am not able to locate where it is.

Comment: It is "list**e**ner.ora"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will find listener.ora in here:

> %ORACLE_HOME%/network/admin

The usual problem is that %ORACLE_HOME% isn't set as a system variable and not exposed to a command shell.

My quickest way to locate ORACLE_HOME from the command shell is:

```
C:\>where sqlplus
The full path to the executable will show. Go there.
Go one up, and add /network/admin
```

Another approach is to look in the registry.

**Watch out for variable TNS_ADMIN which overrides Oracle default network directory.**

Comment: Hi - I looked in the registry. I went to Oracle_home and then to Network/Admin folders. I dont see Listener.Ora file here

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/network.102/b14213/listener.htm) and [this](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/network.111/b28317/listener.htm#NETRF292). These were obtained by simply Googling "[location of listener.ora windows](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/network.111/b28317/listener.htm#NETRF292)". If, for whatever reason, your file isn't located in one of the default locations, you can use the Windows [find command](http://www.howtogeek.com/206097/how-to-use-find-from-the-windows-command-prompt/) to pick up the file.